# How to access WPF control properties outside of main class

Tags: c#, wpf, properties, controls

I have a 'public static' class that gets called on application startup. In this class, I'm trying to set the "IsEnabled" and "IsChecked" properties of several check-boxes. I had no problem doing this in MainWindow.xaml.cs but when I try to reference the check-boxes in my custom class, the check-box names aren't resolving in Intellisense/auto-complete. I also get the error, "The name 'cbx_NameOfMyBox' does not exist in the current context"

How can I access control properties outside of MainWindow.xaml.cs?

```
namespace Widget
{
    public static class StartupSequence
    {
        public static void Begin()
        {
            GetDomain.Start();
            cbx_GpoUpdate.IsEnabled = false;


            return;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not use statics for sharing data. If you need to share data, WPF has the App.XAML for this.

Comment: Also, time for my MVVM Disclaiemr: WPF/UWP and XAML were designed with the MVVM pattern in mind. While you can use other patterns and approaches, doing so misses about 90% of the features and runs into problems at any other corner. Also not a lot of people will be able to help you. | I wrote a short intro into MVVM a few years back: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b1a8bf14-4acd-4d77-9df8-bdb95b02dbe2/lets-talk-about-mvvm?forum=wpf

Comment: Is your `StartupSequence` not in the same assembly as the `MainWindow`? Named controls are internal fields by default, so you cannot access them from a different assembly. I also second @Christopher vote for MVVM. If you really want to go ahead with this approach, you can make a public property that returns the named control. Be aware however that this kind of code is considered a strong smell in WPF.

Comment: Thanks guys, guess I'll research MVVM and give that a shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SUGGESTIONS:**

1. You need to implement MVVM and bind the data.
2. If you are going to use static class to share data, then i would suggest using singleton class. You should not make the class static. You should make the constructor of the class as private. Then, create a static property which can return your class. (just do some google search to learn about singleton)

**SOLUTION TO YOUR ISSUE (as a quick fix) :**

You are doing it in the opposite direction. Main purpose of static property is that it can be accessed from anywhere in the project (provided the namespaces are properly referenced). So, instead of trying to access your control from the static class, do it the other way. In your xaml.cs (Control's code behind), like when the control is loaded or initiated or somewhere suitable, add like,

```
cbx_GpoUpdate.IsEnabled = StartupSequence.your_boolean_property_for_this
```

You need to have a boolean property in your static class to store the required data and when the control is initiated, you refer it. You can also created different other properties for different controls and in each controls' code behind you can refer them whenever they are loaded or a button is clicked or in any other event scenario.

Note: I started exactly the way you are doing it (in code behind) but after several months and projects later, i learned it the hard way that MVVM pattern is the best for WPF. Now, 3 years straight, all my projects are in MVVM. Start to learn MVVM and move to it as soon as possible. Cheers.

Comment: Thank you brosky!